# Variance over a 3D array in R

Tags: r, matrix, var, dimensions

Working on a 3d array:

```
ar3d <- array(floor(100 * runif(100 * 20 * 30)), dim = c(100, 20, 30))
```

I am confused why

```
length(apply(ar3d, MARGIN = 1, FUN = "sd"))
# [1] 100
```

While

```
dim(apply(ar3d, MARGIN = 1, FUN = "var"))
# [1] 900 100
```

How can I calculate the variance amongst the 20 * 30 values as fast as possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `var`, you should use `var(c(x))` instead of `var(x)` if you want to obtain a scalar rather a covariance matrix.

When you type `?var`, you see

> var, cov and cor compute the variance of x and the covariance or
> correlation of x and y if these are vectors. If x and y are matrices
> then the covariances (or correlations) between the columns of x and
> the columns of y are computed.

You can try it out like

```
> ar3d <- array(floor(100 * runif(100 * 20 * 30)), dim = c(100, 20, 30))

> length(apply(ar3d, 1, \(x) var(c(x))))
[1] 100

> length(apply(ar3d, 1, var))
[1] 90000

> length(apply(ar3d, 1, sd))
[1] 100
```

Comment: Many thanks @ThomasIsCoding, this puzzled me for quite some time.